# Angular 5 HttpClient map Observable returned to local member of the component

Tags: angular, service, components, httpclient

I have a service defines that simply does the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingService {

  settingsForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private httpErrorHandlerService : HttpErrorHandlerService) { }

    getPreference()   {
      return this.http.get<Preference>('/api/admin/config');
    }
```

Here is snippet of Preference Model

```
export class Preference {

 utilityName : string;
 utilitySupportUrl : string
 utilitySupportPhone : string;
 utilitySupportEmail : string;
 utilityPayBillUrl : string;
 utilityUrl : string;
 defaultLocale : string;

 showTOC : Boolean;
 showLastBilledDate : Boolean ;

 notificationRangeInHours : String;
```

In my component..

```
settingsForm: FormGroup;
  public utilityPreference: Preference = new Preference();

 constructor(private settingService: SettingService, private messageService: MessageService, private httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandlerService, private fb: FormBuilder, @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: IAppConfig) {
     this.settingService.getPreference().subscribe((data)  => { 
     console.log(data); 
     this.utilityPreference = data;
    });
console.log("====Component's preference:"+ JSON.stringify(this.utilityPreference));
```

My issue is my component is not able to get the copy of the Observable returned by the subscribe on my service. I was setting it as

```
this.utilityPreference = data;
```

In other words if i do `this.utilityPreference.utilityName`, i see NULL

Can someone point me in the right direction here ?

Comment: try to do the subscription on ngOnInit

Comment: try to avoid subscriptions within the constructer, as @Ricardo says, try onInit,or in its own method

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are facing is that settingService.getPreference() is asynchronous. So your console.log evaluates first and then, some time later, getPreference() returns and subscribe block gets executed.

```
constructor(...) {
  this.settingService.getPreference().subscribe(data => { 
     this.utilityPreference = data;
     console.log('second', this.utilityPreference)
  });
  console.log('first', this.utilityPreference)
}
```

Also as others suggested, consider moving the logic to ngOnInit. Constructors should be thin, and only handle the dependency injection.

Comment: So are you saying moving this code to ngOnInit will resolve my issue here?